# Creating a custom widget like Form Aware Value Relation Widget

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.18

I'm trying to get to know how to make my own widgets to be used in the Edit Widget.
I have looked at this plugin here and it is very usefull:
https://github.com/elpaso/qgis-formawarevaluerelationwidget

I'm trying to make a custom widget which will have a combobox and a few small buttons (like flash feature, zoom to, pan to)

In the example i have created from the form aware relation widget i can succesfully create a combobox.

```
class FormToolsRelationWidgetWrapper(QgsEditorWidgetWrapper):

    def __init__(self, vl, fieldIdx, editor, parent):
        """
        QgsVectorLayer* vl, int fieldIdx, QWidget* editor, QWidget* parent
        """
        some init stuff here...



    def createWidget(self, parent):
        #self.mComboBox = TestWidget(parent)
        #self.mComboBox = TestWidget()
        self.mComboBox = QComboBox(parent)
        QObject.connect( self.mComboBox, SIGNAL( "currentIndexChanged( int )" ), self, SLOT( "valueChanged()" ) )
        return self.mComboBox
```

The result is this:

[image: combobox looks ok]

Looks very good. And i know i have not yet populated the combobox with data.

If i instead activate a widget i have created with this code (with TestWidget(parent) ):

```
class TestWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # create a combobox
        combobox_1 = QComboBox(self)
        combobox_1.addItem("Item 1")

        # create a combobox with a parent widget
        combobox_2 = QComboBox(self)
        combobox_2.addItem("Item A")
        combobox_2.addItem("Item B")
        combobox_2.addItem("Item C")

        # layout
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(combobox_1)
        layout.addWidget(combobox_2)
        layout.addStretch()

        # sets the layout
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

I get his result:
[image: Misplaced comboboxes]

I'm not sure what is wrong. I have test by not assigning QComboBox and QHBoxLayout to self. Without any luck.​
Here the widget does not replace the ID field. i thought this would be replaced with my widget. Like the example with qcombobox.

Any suggestions to make this work?

I can not find any examples/tutorials explaning this. Maybe if it get this sorted i will make a small introduction to this.

Comment: QgsEditorWidgetWrapper has a valid function which needs to return true, else the widget will not be shown in the correct place. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QgsEditorWidgetWrapper has a valid function which needs to return true, else the widget will not be shown in the correct place. This solved my problem.

eg.

```
def valid(self):
    return  isinstance(self.editor, QComboBox) or \
            isinstance(self.editor, QListWidget) or \
            isinstance(self.editor, QLineEdit) or \
            isinstance(self.editor, QWidget)
```